# How can you get the list of app installed on a phone with phonegap or cordova?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

Can I get the list of installed app on IOS/Android devices using phonegap/cordova?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is not possible for iOS.  For Android you may want to take a look at [this plugin](https://github.com/KIvanow/installedApps).

This uses

```
android.content.pm.PackageManager
```

to get a list of installed apps and return details about them.  You could also implement your own plugin to do this, check out the Android SDK documentation for PackageManager [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html).

Comment: Thanks I will check it out. This will be a private app, so I will not be submitting to the app store.